# MAPI Cdo on Server 2k8 R2?

Tags: exchange, windows-server-2008-r2

I'm testing [MFCMapi](http://www.codeplex.com/MFCMAPI) and the [Exchange CDO 1.2.1](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=E17E7F31-079A-43A9-BFF2-0A110307611E&displaylang=en) on a Windows Server 2008 R2 PC and I continually get a

```
Err: 0x8004010F=MAPI_E_NOT_FOUND
```

Am I correct in assuming that the Exchange CDO pack does not work properly on 2008 R2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The final solution I found was that the R2 Server needed to be rebooted before the CDO pack would work properly. I was able to reproduce this consistently with Server 2008 R2 systems and the MAPI cdo pack.

Comment: Yes installing Exchange CDO 1.2.1 have its quirks. Sometimes needs a reboot and also if there was an older version installed, you need to uninstall it first even though installing over the old one gives no errors, it just won't work.

Answer (score 1):

Search engines are amazing. Hopefully this helps.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/179639

http://www.bing.com/search?q=MAPI_E_NOT_FOUND&FORM=MSNH11&qs=n